# How can I get max value from a For Each Loop

Tags: vb.net

The below code will give all numerical directory names in the specified folder.  How can I get the max value and total count from the produced list?

```
    Dim DirInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\Data")
    For Each FolderInfo In DirInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
        If IsNumeric(FolderInfo.Name) Then
             '
             '
             '
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: What do you think you'd need in that code to compute a maximum value and a count? Surely you can at least put the variable definitions?

Comment: Firstly, if you only care about folders and not files, you should be calling `EnumerateDirectories` rather than `EnumerateFileSystemInfos`.  Secondly, if you only care about the paths/names and not other info then you should be using `Directory` rather than `DirectoryInfo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using linq:

```
Dim DirInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\Data")
Dim list = DirInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos().Where(Function(x) IsNumeric(x.Name)).Select(Function(x) Double.Parse(x.Name)).ToList()
Dim max = list.Max()
Dim count = list.Count()
```

Comment: You don't need the argument to the `Max` call.